# Как организовать потоки в Android приложении?

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

`AsynkTask, Handler, Observable`
Почти все имеет статус Deprivated, но с хэндлером отдельная история, там блок кода становится желтым. Просит сделать его статическим, но не то что бы это помогало. Как бы вы реализовывали простую ситуацию?

1. заполняете поля
2. жмете кнопку
3. OkHTTP клиент отправляет запрос (и тут уже нужен другой поток)
4. а потом вернуть результат в основной и сказать, что вы зашли или неверно ввели пароль
   Пытаюсь все по красоте делать, что бы без желтой мочи в коде. Вот [тут](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)
   вообще говорят использовать `java.util.concurrent` и допустим я согласен, но я вообще не понимаю как.

Неужели котлиновские корутины победили? Пишу именно java но у меня уже задействовано множество библиотек на нем.

Comment: корутины определенно победили) НО! кроме них есть еще RxJava.

Comment: Не нужны вам никакие другие потоки, все есть из коробки: `client.newCall(request).enqueue(callback)`.

Comment: @YuraIvanov так-то оно так, но вдруг нам с запроса вернется количество кругов на экране? Как нам их нарисовать? Ведь UI можно трогать только с основного потока

Comment: callback вызывается в главном потоке. круги можно.

Comment: корутины конечно победили, но Thread + runOnUiThread на крайняк никто не отменил. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42274500/5479247